# How to get the value of time in a datetime picker and use it in an if condition

Tags: c#, ms-access

We need to get the value of time in a datetime picker and store it a database and use it in an if condition for us to know who among the employees are late. Please help us. Thanks. :D

Comment: What part do you want help with? or do you want us to code the entire project for you?

Comment: just the syntax on how to do that.. thank you.. :)

Comment: This is very... vague. What should the condition be?

Comment: This is obviously more than a syntax question with the multiple parts. Besides, any DateTime picker would be a control, and you haven't told us your front end.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to compare 2 dates... if that is your question then you can simply do it by comparing the date's Ticks like this

```
if(mydate.Ticks == myconditiondatetime.Ticks)
{//..... your code}
```

If that is not what u are asking... please be little clear about your question....